# Any better approach for cookie management in react using firebase for authentication

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Below is my code which I assume performs the following operation
If the user closes the tab and opens it again it will retrieve the **idToken** from the cookie verify it and log out the user after the expiration of the cookie.

But, I feel that this is kind of a bad approach. Is, there any other way I can do it.

```js
// Importing react
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";


// Importing navigate from react-router-dom
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

// Importing LoginSingupToast for displaying toast
import { LoginSignupToast } from "../Toasts/LoginSignupToast.tsx";

// Importing cookies from universal-cookie
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

// Importing lottie react
import Lottie from "lottie-react";

// Importing loading animation
import LoadingAnimation from "../Animations/Loading.json";

// Importing server URL
import { serverURL } from "../URLS.js";

// Protected  to check for authentication
export const ProtectedCheck = ({ children }) => {
    const cookies = useMemo(() => new Cookies(), []);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // state for loading
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    // Verifying the user
    const [verifyToken, setVerifyToken] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        fetch(`${serverURL}/verifyToken`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                token: cookies.get("Auth Token").tokenId ?? "",
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
            if (data.status === false) {
                LoginSignupToast(data?.message ?? "An error occured. Please try again.", "error");
            }
            setLoading(false);
            setVerifyToken(data.status);
        });
    }, []);

    // Checking if the cookie is there or not
    useEffect(() => {
        const authToken = cookies.get("Auth Token");
        if (authToken) {
            const expiryTime = authToken.time;
            const timeRemaining = expiryTime - Date.now();
            const timeOutFunction = setTimeout(() => {
                setVerifyToken(false);
                cookies.remove("Auth Token");
                LoginSignupToast("Session timed out. Please login again.", "error");
                navigate("/authentication");
            }, timeRemaining);
            return () => clearTimeout(timeOutFunction);
        }
    }, [cookies, navigate]);


    if (loading) {
        return (<div
            style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                height: "100vh",
                overflow: "hidden",
            }}
        >
            <div>
                <Lottie style={{ height: "120px" }} animationData={LoadingAnimation} loop />
            </div>
        </div>)
    }

    else {
        if (verifyToken) {
            return (
                <>
                    {children}
                </>
            )
        } else {

            return (
                // Navigating to the authentication page
                <Navigate to="/authentication" />
            )
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```